# Need for an augmented grammar

Tags: formal-grammars, parsers, lr-k

The question is under the concept of LR parser. 
Suppose the original grammar is
S->AA
A->aA|b

Is it necessary to add an additional rule S'->S to make it as augmented grammar?
In short, I want to know the use of augmented grammar.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you follow the canonical conversion of augmented grammars, a first step is adding a new start symbol $S'$ and the production $S' \to S$, since the algorithm may later "change" $S$.

However, it may not be necessary at all times. If you ask whether or not it is necessary specifically in this case, why don't you try without it and check if you get a valid answer?